# How to avoid HTTP call from chained angular subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular13, rxjs7

I have a situation where I call an HTTP service to get data back, then based on that data I need to immediately make another HTTP call.  Normally I'd `pipe` the first output to a `switchMap` and be done.  That is now being done from inside a route subscription, so I'm not seeing how to get rid of the inner call.

```
this.route.queryParamMap
  .pipe(switchMap(params => someService.get(params))
  .subscribe(x => {
    // do other things with x

    someService.getOtherThing(x.id).subscribe(...)
  })
```

I can't call `getOtherThing(x.id)` until the `get(params)` call completes.  How do I avoid that service call from within the subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
this.route.queryParamMap.pipe(
  switchMap(params => someService.get(params)),
  concatMap((x) => {
    // do other things with x
    return someService.getOtherThing(x.id)
  })
).subscribe((response) => console.log('Your response'));
```

`concatMap` will wait for `someService.get(params)` to be completed in order to trigger `someService.getOtherThing(x.id)`